# Will this where clause always return false?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to optimize a rather complex query and I think I found a bug in the process.  I'm waiting on clarification on what, exactly, the following check is *supposed* to be checking for, but in the meantime, I'm pretty sure this where clause in one of the subqueries will always return false.  Am I correct?

```
where dateField between GetDate() and DateAdd(m, -6,dateField)
```

Am I wrong in my interpretation that this would have to be after (or equal to) right now AND before 6 months before itself , which would never be true?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `BETWEEN` isn't symmetrical. The value being tested has to be greater than (or equal) to the first mentioned value and lower (or equal) to the second mentioned value.

If the value being tested is greater than the second mentioned value then it can never match.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it your self with variations of this code:

```
declare @basedate datetime = dateadd(month, -7, current_timestamp);

with digits as (
   SELECT * 
   FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9) ) n(digit)
), 
numbers as (
select d1.digit + (d2.digit*10) + (d3.digit*100) number
from digits d1
cross join digits d2
cross join digits d3
),
dates as (
    select dateadd(day, number, @basedate) as dateField 
    from numbers
)
select dateField, case when dateField between GetDate() and DateAdd(m, -6,dateField) then 'True' else 'False' end as Result
from dates
--OPTIONAL, if you just want to see the "True" results (hint: there are none, which is why I left it off... so you can see the query does run)
-- WHERE dateField between GetDate() and DateAdd(m, -6,dateField)
order by dateField
```

This will check a value for every date from before 6 months prior to the current date to beyond 6 months after the current date.

Sure enough, it never returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this where clause **always** return false?

Technically speaking it could also yield `UNKNOWN` when column is nullable

[NULL and UNKNOWN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **When null values are present in data, logical and comparison operators can potentially return a third result of UNKNOWN instead of just TRUE or FALSE**

---

For this particular example, it cannot be `TRUE`(it may be `FALSE`/`UNKNOWN`).

Comment: Pedantic - especially when NO ONE has said anything about nullability.

Comment: @SMor Keyword: "always"  :). Skipping Nullability creates confusion that is why it is worth mentioning for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817870/combine-individual-sql-server-queries-into-1-query)